# Wordpress changes normal url into $_GET variables

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, get, woocommerce

I am facing a problem (or two) here.

The filter function in wordpress is not working when you change pages. Now I found out that the problem is the url itself:

`http://www.example.com?swoof=1&orderby=title_asc&paged=2`
this one is not working, it is not ordered by title anymore, however, this one is working fine:

http://www.example.com/page/2?swoof=1&orderby=title_asc

Now the problem is, when I look at the code inside the browser (console F12), i see that the pagination url is just like the working link, but when I click on it, it changes itself to a `$_GET` - `&pages=2` in this case -  anyway.

How can I assure that OR the link does not change to a `$_GET` OR that from whatever reason the `$_GET['paged']` variable will not be interfering with the order anymore? Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I keep forgetting to put them in between quotes

Comment: Maybe stating setup details that you are using, like Woocommerce, would help people help you better.

Comment: I did not know where the problem came from, and thus did not know what was the important information. Since noone asked, neither gave a response, I just deactivated one by one, whereas every plugin with Ajax gave me the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. In the settings of the Woocommerce filters, uncheck the "Try to ajaxify the shop". That way the links stops changing to `$_GET` variables.